# Format of Text Based Dataset in Python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

So I have just started using scikit-learn for machine learning on Python. I have gone for unsupervised learning on labelled text data. However I cannot figure out what the format of the .csv file containing the dataset before converting it to a NumPy array should look like. For example:

I stored the a string under the 'String' label and the boolean values denoting whether the string is acceptable or not as the column 'Status'. I understand this kind of labelling is wrong. But I haven't found articles that clearly specify what to do.

Comment: Your question is way too vague. If you're having trouble parsing a CSV file into an array or pandas dataframe then you should give a representative example of the format of the file and some of the code you tried.

Comment: I am having trouble with storing the labelled data in a CSV file. I realize there is a specific way one should do it. I am handling text data and am planning to use the Naive-Bayes classifier to do categorisation of the data into "Relevant" and "Irrelevant" categories. Here's how I labelled my training set:

| String | Status|

My CSV file has 2 columns, the string column holds all the strings I have looked through and the status is the label (boolean) where 1 means string is relevant and 0 means irrelevant. I read somewhere 3 columns should be present.

Comment: This should help: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html#extracting-features-from-text-files

Answer (score 0):

Try importing one of the example datasets e.g.:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
makemoons()
```

The sklearn example codes is pretty good in my experience e.g. [this one](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html)